# Create relative path to connection string attachdbfilename in app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

This is my EF entities connection string, at the moment the `AttachDbFile` string is the full path of the database, and won't work when I deploy the site. How do I make a relative path for my `AttachDbFile`?

```
<add name="demoDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SalongModel.csdl|res://*/SalongModel.ssdl|res://*/SalongModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=&quot;C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\SVCloginLib\App_Data\demoDB.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is the interesting part:

```
attachdbfilename=&quot;C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\SVCloginLib\App_Data\demoDB.mdf&quot;
```

I've tried the most obvious ones to me:

```
<add name="demoDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SalongModel.csdl|res://*/SalongModel.ssdl|res://*/SalongModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|demoDB.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<add name="demoDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SalongModel.csdl|res://*/SalongModel.ssdl|res://*/SalongModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=&quot;.\App_Data\demoDB.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<add name="demoDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SalongModel.csdl|res://*/SalongModel.ssdl|res://*/SalongModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=&quot;~\App_Data\demoDB.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And loads more, all give me:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

Its for a c# Rest service, if it makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `|DataDirectory|` value to specify the `App_Data` folder in your project. You do however need to separate the value with a slash:

```
<add name="demoDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SalongModel.csdl|res://*/SalongModel.ssdl|res://*/SalongModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\demoDB.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

You may also have to set the value for `DataDirectory` like this in your application's initialisation method (e.g. `Application_Start` in `global.asax.cs`):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
```

Comment: Its for a c# Rest service, if it makes any difference

Comment: Add that code into your `Application_Start` routine.

Comment: I just get a ton of errors http://i.gyazo.com/57aa4459cb3f0f5b167b34849edc9eab.png

Comment: I don't have a global.asax.cs in my project folder

Comment: You can add a `global.asax` file, and copy past that line of code into the correct routine. You must have copied it incorrectly to get those errors though.

Comment: This command `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",
         Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));`works within `MyDbContext: DbContext` constructor!